# Manipulate non-global variables from fileevent handler

Tags: tcl

Is there a way to manipulate non-global variables from a fileevent handler? Consider the following minimal server:

```
proc initState {stateName} {
    upvar $stateName state
    set state(foo) bar
    set state(baz) bla
    # ...
    return
}

proc handleConnection {stateName newsock clientAddress clientPort} {
    upvar $stateName state
    fconfigure $newsock -blocking 0
    fconfigure $newsock -buffering line
    fileevent $newsock readable [list handleData $newsock]
    return
}

proc handleData {f} {
    if {[eof $f]} {
        fileevent $f readable {}
        close $f
        return
    }
    gets $f line
    puts $f ok
    # need to modify state here...
    return
}

proc runServer {port} {
    array set state {}
    initState state
    socket -server {handleConnection state} $port
    vwait forever
}

runServer 1234
```

Is there any possibility to manipulate the `state` array created in the scope of `runServer` or is the only way to do this making `state` a global variable?

I'm pretty new to Tcl, if I were using C I would simply pass a pointer to `state` into the event handler but unfortunately Tcl does not allow that. Am I doing anything weird here, is there a more Tcl-ish way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simply not going to work. The issue is that Tcl's stack frames do not persist in the way that what you want would require.

The standard options to work around this are:

1. Keep the state in a **global array** that is indexed by a "connection token" (e.g., the name of the channel). Remember that arrays are indexed by strings; composite keys like “`sock42,hostname`” are quite legal.
2. Keep the state in a **namespace** named after the connection token. If you're using Tcl 8.5, the `namespace upvar` command makes this *much* easier.
3. Keep the state in a TclOO **object** (requires Tcl 8.6 *or* the separate TclOO package for 8.5) or use a different object system (e.g., [incr Tcl], XOTcl; these are available for many Tcl versions).
4. Keep the state in a **coroutine** (requires Tcl 8.6). This effectively gives you a named stack (and lets you write your code so it is apparently “straight line” instead of driven by callback) but its version requirement is *strict*.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation, using namespaces for this is an interesting possibility.

Comment: @user Another possibility is to generate a unique token name per connection and call the global array that, using `upvar #0 $token ary; do something with $ary(this) and $ary(that)`. This is how Tcl's `http` package works.